# What are the Possible Network Errors when using Node.js axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

While using the node.js `axios`, I have encountered 2 errors `ENOTFOUND` and `ECONNABORTED` that my code eventually is able to handle.

Searched the [axios github repo](https://github.com/axios/axios) but was not able to find a list of possible errors. Additionally, searching the repo code for `ENOTFOUND` and `ECONNABORTED` returned zero result.

**Motivation:** I want to show the user a relevant and human-friendly error message when there is problem connecting to an API endpoint, differentiating between API service being down, user having network connectivity problems, or an unauthorized API request. Instead of a generic *Unable to connect.* or *Error encountered: 500* error messages.

**Question:** Is there a list of possible network error codes that may be thrown by `axios` and what they mean?

Comment: These errors are not from axios but rather a HTTP connection error. The best place to look at would be at Node's [HTTP module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html).  However, these errors are at the network layer, not application layer. Any particular reason why would you want to catch them?

Comment: these are not axios-specific, they're networking errors specific to Node.js (the errors themselves are pretty universal, but the error code and string is generated by Node.js). if you run into one of these, something has gone _properly_ wrong, like your network device getting disabled.

Comment: Why not just this: `catch(error => {if (error.response) {//response error} else if (error.request) {//request error} else {//other error (error.message)}})`

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco I want to show the user a relevant error message when there is problem connecting to an API endpoint, differentiating between API service being down, user having network connectivity problems, or an unauthorized API request. Instead of a generic *Unable to connect.* error.

Comment: @Abk I will like to show a more specific and human-friendly error message to the user so the problem can be easily identified. Hence I will like to catch the various network errors.

Comment: There is also http status code. You can easily create status:message dictionary.

Comment: @bigless Can you elaborate on your suggested *status:message dictionary* ?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors

Comment: I would recommend **against** showing the user an error message that is related to configuration. Errors like `ENOTFOUND` and `ECONNABORTED` are **not** HTTP status code, they are network errors. This is userful for the developer, but for the end user, they just need to see an error 500

Comment: Another way of seeing this, is that this errors are not gonna happen if the API server is down or if a web page is not found. They are gonna happen if the developer/devops put the wrong api URL in the code, or the wrong Port. Or if the API server hostname can't be resolved cause of the DNS servers gone wrong or VPC is incorrectly configured.

Comment: Shouldn't you show a 502 error if you're working in a reverse proxy and your request sent back a ECONNREFUSED?

Answer (score 1):

Example of custom http messages based on comments above. There is also [sweet spot](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) for this handling.

```
const statusCodeMsgs = {
 404: 'Not found',
 408: 'Timeout',
 500: 'Internal server error'
 //and so on
}

function rejectCb(error) {
  let msg;
  if (error.response) {
    msg = statusCodeMsgs[error.response.status];
  }
  console.log(msg||error.code);
}
```